# how to install elasticcache client memcached on PHP 8.0 on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, memcached, ebextensions

I am tring to install elasiccache client on AWS beanstalk but all ways fail,

thanks

I created folder .ebextensions and file package.config
in this file

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    jq: []
    amazon-linux-extras: []
    libjpeg-turbo-devel: []
    memcached: []
```

but geting error memcached class is not found
could you please help

Comment: [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/mem-ug/Appendix.PHPAutoDiscoverySetup.html) is a details guide on Installing the ElastiCache cluster client for PHP. Did you try those steps?

Comment: Hi, this is for EC2. I am using Elstaicbeanstalk no documentation for php8 on Elstaicbeanstalk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that may help someone

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    jq: []
    amazon-linux-extras: []
    libjpeg-turbo-devel: []
    memcached: []
    libmemcached-devel: []
```